# Failed to finish transaction because it has been rolled back

Tags: ignite

I have the need to expire records after they have been in the cache for more than a year, therefore I set the expiry policy like below when creating a cache:

```
final Duration ttl = new Duration(TimeUnit.DAYS, 365);
igniteCacheConfig.setExpiryPolicyFactory(ModifiedExpiryPolicy.factoryOf(ttl));
```

But if I use this policy, then after processing around 200K-400K records, then we got this exception:

*Failed to finish transaction because it has been rolled back*

The exception is happening when I am trying to use those records, but it looks like Ignite in the background is identifying them as obsolete, therefore my transaction fails; it is like Ignite is not honoring or following the period I defined.

This cache also has an index and it under a pessimistic transaction, I am not sure if those could be related to the issue.

I am able to reproduce the same issue on Apache Ignite 2.10 and 2.11, and again, if I don't use this expiry policy, then everything works just fine.

**Stack trace:**

Caused by: org.apache.ignite.internal.transactions.IgniteTxRollbackCheckedException: Failed to finish transaction because it has been rolled back [timeout=60000, tx=GridDhtTxLocal[xid=30feff79e71-00000000-0f2e-8544-0000-000000000001, xidVersion=GridCacheVersion [topVer=254707012, order=1643227639555, nodeOrder=1], nearXidVersion=GridCacheVersion [topVer=254707012, order=1643227639543, nodeOrder=2], concurrency=PESSIMISTIC, isolation=REPEATABLE_READ, state=PREPARING, invalidate=false, rollbackOnly=false, ....]]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.transactions.IgniteTxAdapter.rollbackException(IgniteTxAdapter.java:797)
.....

Comment: If you have a runnable reproducer I'd suggest creating a ticket in the [Ignite Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/IGNITE/issues/) for this.